# Is it true that every point in a space equipped with the Hausdorff topology is closed?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that every point in a space equipped with the Hausdorff topology is closed?

I am assuming this is true but am having a difficult time proving it. Fix $a \in X$ where $X$ is equipped with the Hausdorff topology. If I can show that $X \setminus \{a\}$ is open then I am finished.

I know that $\forall y \in X \setminus \{a\}$ there exists $U$ and $V$ such that $a \in U$ and $y \in V$ and $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

In general, I have been having a difficult time with these types of proofs. The fact that $U$ and $V$ change based on my choice of $y$ causes some confusion.

Comment: For every $y\in X-\left\{ a\right\} $ there is an open set $V_{y}$
such that $y\in V_{y}$ and $a\notin V_{y}$. Now note that the union
of these open sets (which is open itself) equalizes $X-\left\{ a\right\} $. So $X-\left\{ a\right\} $ is open, i.e. $\left\{ a\right\} $ is
closed.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, points are closed iff the topology is T1, and Hausdorff implies T1. A topology is T1 if for every pair of points $x,y$ there are open sets $U,V$ s.t. $U$ contains $x$ but not $y$ and $V$ contains $y$ but not $x$.

If points are closed, clearly the topology is T1. Conversely, take a point $x$ of your space $X$. You want to show that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open. For each $y\in X\setminus \{x\}$, pick an open $V_y$ s.t. $x\notin V_y$. Then $X\setminus \{x\}=\bigcup_{y\in X\setminus\{x\}}V_y$ is a union of open sets and is therefore open.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**   we could use the fact: Intersections of closed sets is a closed set, in order to construct singleton $\{x\}$,if we can show that in Hausdorff then automatically it will be a closed set.

1. For any $y \in X \ \& \ y \neq x $ there exist two open set such that

   $x \in U_y \ \& \ y \in V_y: U_y \bigcap V_y = \phi   \Rightarrow  y \notin \overline {U_{y}}$ (since it's Hausdorff)

2.for any $y \neq x,\Rightarrow y \notin \overline  U_y \Rightarrow $   $y \notin \bigcap_{y \in X -\{x\} } \overline {U_{y}} \Rightarrow  \bigcap_{y \in X -\{x\} } \overline {U_{y}}  =\{x\}$

but $\overline {U_{y}}  $ is close set for each $y$ therefore $  \bigcap_{y \in X -\{x\} } \overline {U_{y}} =\{x\} $ is close set

*Q.E.D*